# wget "mirroring" pdf linked to different domain

Tags: javascript, regex, url, download, wget

[Webpage](http://www.yowconference.com.au/brisbane/events_tracks/event_details.html?eventId=2636) contains a [link to a pdf](http://gotocon.com/dl/jaoo-brisbane-2010/slides/ObieFernandez_TheRichGetRicherRails3.pdf) (note the different domains).

I can use wget to directly download the pdf, but cannot seem to identify the correct wget command line options to "mirror" the webpage including this linked pdf. I tried to use combinations of options like

- -p
- --span-hosts
- -D
- --accept

with no success.

Can wget (or some other command line tool) be used to download linked pdf-s?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the pdf link is shown in browsers, the page source does not contain the download link. So `wget` does not get to see/follow the link, as it doesn't really "process" the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing http://www.yowconference.com.au/brisbane/data/35.js. (I found this url with HttpFox.) After formatting the code (for example with http://jsbeautifier.org/) it's easy to grep out the url of pdf files.